# Converting CSV column to list of lists in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I have a csv column with some labels in it. I need to convert it to list of lists.
**ex:**

```
type1(heading)  
string1  
string2  
string3  
string4
```

converting this directly to,

```
type1 = [[string1],[string2],[string3],[string4]]
```

Comment: so what is the issue? what did you try?

Comment: Used pandas lib to read csv and then converted the column to a list. Then, I am having problem converting it to list of lists. @AnandSKumar

Comment: Can you show the code you are currently using?

Comment: If you give an actual example piece of the file it is more worth than just some text. We need to know what differentiates the text from the headings

Answer (score 1):

You can try the `csv` module. For example, given a test.txt file:

```
header_a,header_b,header_c
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
```

You can write:

```
import csv

with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    headers = list(reader.next())
    result = [[list(c) for c in row] for row in reader]
    for i, header_name in enumerate(headers):
        print header_name, [row[i] for row in result]
```

The result will be:

```
header_a [['1'], ['4'], ['7']]
header_b [['2'], ['5'], ['8']]
header_c [['3'], ['6'], ['9']]
```

The document of `csv` module is [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

Comment: Thank you! But I need to convert elements under same header to a list of list.

Comment: @javi_parni: I've updated my answer, see if that's what you need.

Answer (score 1):

It seems python has a native lib to deal with such tasks. Maybe you should take a look at https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html